# How report an average confidence interval when width varies along a gradient?

Tags: confidence-interval, prediction, glmm

I used Ben Bolker's [easyPredCI function](http://ms.mcmaster.ca/~bolker/R/misc/foxchapter/bolker_chap.html) to generate standard errors and confidence intervals from a GLMM (this function creates population-level predictions by ignoring the random effect).  When I plot the predicted responses (abundance) and confidence intervals along a gradient of one of my explanatory variables (proportion cover of grasses, 0 to 1) while holding others constant, it looks like this:

[image]

I want to interpret these results in a simple manner by reporting something like: "for every 10% increase in grass cover, abundance decreases by X%."  That part is easy enough, but I'd like to include a confidence interval in that statement, and I'm not sure how to do that considering that the width varies along the gradient.  I could use the mean of the width along the entire gradient, but I'm guessing there might be a better way.  Any suggestions?  I can simplify some code, if needed, but it seems like this question is general enough that it wouldn't be needed.  Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a confidence interval for $X$ rather than a CI for the fit itself.  In that case, the answer is routinely reported in the regression output.

Comment: The graph looks like a simultaneous confidence band for the regression curve. You may not want this.  But if you do an average confidence interval does not make sense. As Bill Huber said you can get confidence intervals for the regression parameters.  If you want to pick one from the simultaneous confidence band fix a value of x and interpret the interval for y given x as the interval.  It changes with x.  These bands can be constructed for prediction or estimation. The prediction band would be wider for prediction intervals than for confidence intervals.